# Am I getting mildly electrocuted by my laptop

Tags: macbook-pro

It feels like I'm getting mildly electrocuted by my Macbook pro a gentle buzzy feeling in my hands when touching it and some times a slightly sharper feeling . I have been using it a lot more during lockdown and haven't been able to sleep even though stopping use hours before bed. I feel as if my whole body is buzzing a bit hmmmm anyone had a similar experience ? Is it mild electrocution ? Thanks

Comment: It is likely a resonance with the switch mode power supply inducing a mild current in the case. I get a similar sensation with the metal body of my phone as well as my laptop when they are charging. Possibly you are also more sensitive to it. Many modern devices are isolated from ground so this tiny current goes through you rather than your power supply.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no danger to you, but there is obviously some leakage from the power supply, likely caused by [capacitive coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_coupling) to the case. This was rarely an issue with devices having a grounded cords, which connected the ground to the case.

Since I find that perceptible "buzz" of leakage annoying on a laptop, I added a 1.3 mm dia. (16 AWG) wire from the mains ground lead, with a paralleled 250 VAC, 0.5 µFd capacitor and 330 kΩ resistor, to a metal part on the case of the laptop. This shorts the AC leakage to ground, getting rid of that "buzz".

[image: AC Leakage Eliminator]

Some explanation:

- Why not simply place a wire to ground? One could, but in an abundance of caution, I added a series capacitor to avoid strain on the power supply insulation... in case of failure, light wire might overheat.
- Why add the resistor? Depending on where in the cycle the mains is, a charge could be left on the capacitor when unplugging the laptop. The resistor quickly bleeds off the charge.

**N.B.** This is potentially dangerous if miswired!! If you are not familiar with electrical devices and wiring, **don't try this.**

Answer (score 0):

There can be a slight current leakage between your MacBook's metal case and other metal/conductive surfaces you may be touching if the two things do not share a common ground. In many situations you can fix it quickly by switching your power adapter from the grounded AC cord to the ungrounded "duck head" adapter, or vice-versa. The grounded AC cord for the power adapter isn't always included anymore, so you might have to pick one up separately.